# Музыкальный проигрыватель на Flash со светомузыкой.

Tags: flash, светомузыка, actionscript-3

Доброго вечера товарищи! Я не специалист по звуку, и даже не любитель, но можно ли в Actionscript 3 как - то реализовать такое? Быть может перехват вот этих вот скачков(извиняюсь, термина не знаю) и на основании некоторых вычислений выполнять некий код, какие идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зверски легко!

С помощью метода SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(), создает снимок спектра звука в текущий момент времени.

[**Документация.**](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum())

> *Создает снимок текущей звуковой волны
> и помещает его в заданный объект
> ByteArray. Значения форматируются как
> нормализованные значения с плавающей
> запятой в диапазоне от -1 до 1. Объект
> ByteArray, передаваемый параметру
> outputArray, перезаписывается новыми
> значениями. Размер созданного объекта
> ByteArray фиксируется на 512 значениях
> с плавающей запятой, где первые 256
> значений представляют левый канал, а
> следующие 256 значений — правый.*

```
var s:Sound = new Sound();
var sc:SoundChannel;
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var array:Array;

s.load(new URLRequest("mix.mp3"));
sc = s.play(0,1000);

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spectrum);

var a:Number = 0;

function spectrum(event:Event)
{
   a = 0;
   graphics.clear();
   SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(ba,true,0);

   for(var i=0; i < 256; i=i+8)
   {
     a = ba.readFloat();
     var num:Number = a*360;
     graphics.lineStyle( num/15, 0x0066FF|(num << 8), i );
     graphics.drawCircle(stage.stageWidth/2,stage.stageHeight/2,i);
   }

}
```